# React.js - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

When the component mounts, I'm making an ajax request that returns an Object with an array of objects.

```
getPages() {
  getAllPagesData().then((pages) => {
    let data = pages
    this.setState({ pages });
  });
}
```

Inside this function I can access the data effectively.

`console.log(pages.pages[0].description)`

Prints the correct page description.

In render I'm setting state to a variable to access in my return:

```
render() {

  const pages = this.state.pages.pages
  console.log(pages)

return (
```

That console.log in chrome is:

```
(55) [Object, Object, Object, Object,...
```

I'm then trying to iterate through the array using map:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Nav />
     { pages.map((post, index) => (
```

It breaks the page and the error is: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at Pages.render`

I've tried many different ways to access this object and the array inside of it, but cannot get individual array items to display inside the render function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this line in the render method

```
const pages = this.state.pages.pages || [ ]
```

It is most likely because the `render` method is called before the ajax request is complete. So the `this.state.pages.pages` is `undefined` initially.

Comment: "It is most likely because the render method is called before the ajax request is complete" - ah, that seems likely... Yup, that worked, thanks!